# boto3 DMS enable CloudWatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-dms

I am writing scripts in Python that are creating DMS tasks using the boto3 package. I wonder if there is any way of programatically enabling CloudWatch logging for the tasks? I can't find any option to do this with the create_replication_task function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining `ReplicationTaskSettings` in your `create_replication_task` call. That is an optional parameter. You define the task settings in a JSON string format. You need to add the following in your task settings:

```
"Logging": {
    "EnableLogging": true
}
```

In that way, you can enable CloudWatch logging while creating the task from Python using Boto3.

A sample request would be as follows:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('dms')

response = client.create_replication_task(
    ReplicationTaskIdentifier='string',
    SourceEndpointArn='string',
    TargetEndpointArn='string',
    ReplicationInstanceArn='string',
    MigrationType='full-load'|'cdc'|'full-load-and-cdc',
    TableMappings='string',
    ReplicationTaskSettings="{\"Logging\": {\"EnableLogging\": true}}",
)
```

Reference to `create_replication_task` API is here:

[AWS SDK for Python - Boto3 - AWS DMS - Create Replication Task API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dms.html#DatabaseMigrationService.Client.create_replication_task)

Reference to `ReplicationTaskSettings` parameter is here:

[AWS SDK for Python - Boto3 - AWS DMS - Create Replication Task API - Replication Task Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.html)